# Parsing through a logfile and getting parameter values from different lines

Tags: java, regex, parsing, logfile

I'm trying to parse a logfile and getting specific values from it.
However, it is formatted like this:

```
Information

REASON:
END Fault

TAN    EE           MODE    LND  NFN            TYPE
------+------------+-------+----+--------------+-------
01111  321448       IBW        1 1111- 1- 4- 32 SS4

END
```

How could I get the values from the "table" and match them to the specific parameter? I'm trying to assign the values like 01111 to a String variable.

My code right now looks like this:

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            textblock = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(textblock));

        }
```

Comment: The problem is that you have a single space as delimiter as well. This would mean we couldn't split by `[ ]{2,}`. So the only way would be to find out the length of each section by matching  `+-----+` pieces. That's a bit complicated. So if the sections are fixed length, you could do this manually instead of dynamically.